# How to use nohup on a process already running in background

Tags: linux, unix, nohup

So I have a job running in Background on my unix terminal, I will have to close the ssh terminal after some time and my job has to continue after that as well. How can I use the nohup or any other possible option to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nohup` starts a new process.  You cannot retroactively apply it to a process that you've already started.

However, if the shell from which you launched the job is `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` then the `disown` job-control builtin may provide what you want.  It can either remove the job from job control altogether or just flag the job to not be sent a `SIGHUP` when the parent shell itself receives one.  This is similar, but not necessarily identical, to the effect of starting a process via the `nohup` command.

Note well that your job may still have issues if any of its standard streams is connected to the session's terminal.  That's something that `nohup` typically clobbers preemptively, but `disown` cannot modify after the fact.  You're normally better off anticipating this need and starting the process with `nohup`, but if you're not so foresightful then `disown` is probably your next best bet.

Note also that as a job-control command, `disown` takes a jobspec to identify the job to operate on, not a process ID.  If necessary, you can use the `jobs` builtin to help determine the appropriate jobspec.